# Split File when string is matches exactly

Tags: python

I have a huge text file that I need to split based on matching a 'EKYC' only value. However, when other values with similar pattern show up my script fails.
I am new in Python and it is wearing me out.

```
import sys;
import os;

MASTER_TEXT_FILE=sys.argv[1];
OUTPUT_FILE=sys.argv[2];

L = file(MASTER_TEXT_FILE, "r").read().strip().split("EKYC")
i = 0
for l in L:
    i = i + 1
    f = file(OUTPUT_FILE+"-%d.ekyc" % i , "w")

    print >>f, "EKYC" + l
```

The script breaks when there is EKYCSMRT or EKYCVDA or EKYCTIGO then how can I make the guard to prevent the splitting to occur before the point.

```
This is the content of all of the messages
EKYC
WIK  12
EKYC
WIK  12
EKYCTIGO
EKYC
WIK  13
TTL
EKYCVD
EKYC
WIK  14
TTL  D
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by _"'EKYC' only value"_? Note that if you do: `'foo EKYCSMRT bar'.split('EKYC')` it will return: `['foo ', 'SMRT bar']` Maybe you want to split by `' ECKYC '` (including blanks before and after)? Please clarify. PS: Python doesn't use `;`, nor your code is using `os`.

Comment: if its a huge file (please define your idea of huge) don't read it all up front, read it line by line. I recommend providing a small example input file so we can better understand the issues you face.

Comment: @PaulRooney okay the word huge file might not be useful but what i mean is that in a single file you will have multiple lines with EKYC code. I need to separate each block of EKYC code

Comment: Is the text file line-based? Do you want to split when EKYC is on its own line? or somehow delimited with other contents on the same line? Should it be included in the output?

Comment: @jose.galarza this is a file and what i mean EKYCSMRT, EKYCVD is part of EKYC code the EKYCSMRT and EKYCVD will be between two EKYC block.

Comment: @ephemient yes it is a text file, i need to split EKYC into its own file.

Comment: @NoelAlexMakumuli I wasn't suggesting you post the full large text file. A small representative example input file would be useful, otherwise we can only base our understanding on your description of the file.

Comment: Also what is the expected output?

Comment: Please provide, as an example, a few lines of the input file, and also the desired output(s).

Comment: @jose.galarza there is already some example input in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, you should avoid reading large files into memory all at once. Instead, stream chunks of them at a time.

The sensible chunks of text files are usually lines. This can be done with `.readline()`, but simply iterating over the file yields its lines too.

After reading a line (which includes the newline), you can `.write()` it directly to the current output file.

```
import sys

master_filename = sys.argv[1]
output_filebase = sys.argv[2]

output = None
output_number = 0
for line in open(master_filename):
    if line.strip() == 'EKYC':
        if output is not None:
            output.close()
            output = None
    else:
        if output is None:
            output_number += 1
            output_filename = '%s-%d.ekyc' % (output_filebase, output_number)
            output = open(output_filename, 'w')
        output.write(line)
if output is not None:
    output.close()
```

The output file is closed and reset upon encountering `'EKYC'` on its own line.
Here, you'll notice that the output file isn't (re)opened until right before there is a line to write to it: this avoids creating an empty output file in case there are no further lines to write to it. You'll have to re-order this slightly if you want the `'EKYC'` line to appear in the output file also.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample input file, you need to: `split('\nEKYC\n')`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

MASTER_TEXT_FILE = sys.argv[1]
OUTPUT_FILE = sys.argv[2]

with open(MASTER_TEXT_FILE) as f:
    fdata = f.read()
    i = 0
    for subset in fdata.split('\nEKYC\n'):
        i += 1
        with open(OUTPUT_FILE+"-%d.ekyc" % i, 'w') as output:
            output.write(subset)
```

Other comments:

- Python doesn't use `;`.
- Your original code wasn't using `os`.
- It's recommended to use `with open(<filename>, <mode>) as f: ...` since it handles possible errors and closes the file afterward.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is close to mine. I just added output.write('EKYC') before write subset because the solution was removing the EKYC code. it works like charm.

Comment: Good to hear! PS: The answer that @ephemient gave has a good tip of reading chunks from the file (in the example, one line at the time), which will be very useful if the input file is extremely big (compared to your machine specs).